# How to fix "The argument type 'Icon' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'" in Flutter

Tags: flutter, forms, dart, widget

I'm encountering the following error in my Flutter code:

> ```
> Performing hot restart... Syncing files to device sdk gphone64 x86 64... 
> lib/product_add_edit.dart:48:19: Error: The argument type 'Icon' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
> 'Icon' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/icon.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/icon.dart'). 
>         const Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
>         ^ Restarted application in 867ms.
> ```

I'm trying to create a form input field in my Flutter app and I'm getting the error "The argument type 'Icon' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'".  Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
class ProductAddEdit extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProductAddEdit({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ProductAddEdit> createState() => _ProductAddEditState();
}

class _ProductAddEditState extends State<ProductAddEdit> {
  static final GlobalKey<FormState> globalKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool isAPICallProcess = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text("NodeJS - CRUD App"),
            elevation: 0,
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
          body: ProgressHUD(
            child: Form(
              key: globalKey,
              child: Text("be like Elon Musk to be successfull"),
            ),
            inAsyncCall: isAPICallProcess,
            opacity: .3,
            key: UniqueKey(),
          ),
        ));
  }
  Widget productForm(){
    return SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, top: 10),
          child: FormHelper.inputFieldWidget(
              context,
            const Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
            "Product Name",
              (onValidateVal) {
                if(onValidateVal.isEmpty) {
                  return "Product name can't be empty";
                }
                return null;
              },
              (onSavedVal) {},
            borderColor: Colors.black,
            borderFocusColor: Colors.black,
            textColor: Colors.black,
            hintColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(.7),
            borderRadius: 10,
            showPrefixIcon: false,
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Screenshots:**

[image]

[image]

I intend to have an input field with the `Icons.ac_unit` icon next to the "Product Name" label. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Can you include your `FormHelper.inputFieldWidget`

Comment: Yes, give me a sec

Comment: Hello, I added all the code from my project and also screenshots about inputFieldWidget

Comment: OH sorry, I didn't notice it was coming form  `snippet_coder_utils` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inputFieldWidget` constructor expect a string as second position argument.

```dart
static Widget inputFieldWidget(
    BuildContext context,
    String keyName, // name
```

You need to provide a keyName as string. You can use `prefixIcon` or `suffixIcon` named arguments to provide icon.

```dart
child: FormHelper.inputFieldWidget(
  context,
  "MyKey",
  "Product Name",
  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
  (onValidateVal) {
    if (onValidateVal.isEmpty) {
      return "Product name can't be empty";
    }
    return null;
  },
  (onSavedVal) {},
  borderColor: Colors.black,
  borderFocusColor: Colors.black,
  textColor: Colors.black,
  hintColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(.7),
  borderRadius: 10,
  showPrefixIcon: false,
),
```

More about [`snippet_coder_utils`](https://pub.dev/packages/snippet_coder_utils)

Answer (score 1):

FormHelper.inputFieldWidget(
context,
const Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
"Product Name",
),

Here inputFieldWidget function have both named and positional parameter.

Points to be noted:

1. Named parameter sequence can be anything while calling a function with name parameter(that's the beauty of named parameter)
2. positional parameter in a function calling should maintain the  same sequence as defined in the function.
3. if a function or class constructor have both named and positional parameter (yes this can be possible and same is used in above function), then positional parameter should come before named parameter and should follow rule 1 and 2.

If your case the sequence is correct but you have assigned Icon() to keyName that is of type string, so mismatching of datatype causing the issue.